# Android loading progress bar

Tags: android, view

I'm trying to set a ProgressBar with data taken from a percentage calculation.
I get error in `mProgress.setProgress(progresso)`;

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
String perc = decimalFormat.format(value);
tvPercentuale.setText(perc+"%");

ProgressBar mProgress;
int progresso = Integer.parseInt(perc); 
mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_e);
mProgress.setProgress(progresso);
mProgress.setMax(100);
```

Comment: And what does the error say?

Comment: this is the error:`java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 18:15:40.229: 
at it.chri.reg.Act_22$2.getView(Act_22.java:197)
`

Comment: Please post more of your logcat. And what is Act_22 line 197? Post your xml layout too.

Comment: this is the row 197 ` mProgress.setProgress(progresso);`

Comment: What is your xml layout? Do you call setContentView? What is the value of progresso when you're calling setProgress?